# How to show $\theta < x_{(1)} < x_{(n)} < \theta + 1$ is equivalent to saying that $x_{(n)}-1 < \theta < x_{(1)}$?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

> Let $\theta > 0$ and $x_{(1)} = \min(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ and $x_{(n)} = \max(x_1, \dots, x_n)$. How is $\theta < x_{(1)} < x_{(n)} < \theta + 1$ is
>   equivalent to saying that $x_{(n)}-1 < \theta < x_{(1)}$?

For more context, this is a probability question. Suppose $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are iid with uniform distribution in $(\theta, \theta + 1)$. Then their joint density is
$$f(x_1, \dots, x_n) = \mathbf{1}_{\{\theta < x_{(1)} < x_{(n)} < \theta + 1\}}$$
where $\mathbf{1}$ is the indicator function based on the event $\{\theta < x_{(1)} < x_{(n)} < \theta + 1\}$ as shown above,  $x_{(1)} = \min(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ and $x_{(n)} = \max(x_1, \dots, x_n)$. Without further explanation, my professor said that the condition is equivalent to stating that this event is equivalent to $\{x_{(n)}-1 < \theta < x_{(1)}\}$.

Why is this? I tried working it out and got $\{x_{(n)} - 1 < \theta < \theta + x_{(n)}-x_{(1)} < 0\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\theta < x_{(1)} < x_{(n)} < \theta + 1$ is actually three inequalities:

1. $\theta < x_{(1)}$
2. $x_{(1)} < x_{(n)}$
3. $x_{(n)} < \theta + 1$

The second is a given because of the definition of the two variables, give or take an equals sign. The third can be rearranged into $x_{(n)} - 1 < \theta$, and you can then combine that with the first to get the equivalent form your professor gave.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the conclusion... that $\theta < x_{(1)}$ ... is one of your hypotheses, so that's easy. And it tells you that all of the $x_i$ are larger than $\theta$ as well, since all of the $x_i$ are at *least* as big as their minimum.

The second hypothesis -- that $x_{(n)}$ says that all the $x_i$ are less than $\theta + 1$. So for each $i$, we have
$$
\theta <x_i < \theta + 1.
$$
That means that the max of the $x_i$ is also $< \theta + 1$, so 
$$
x_{(n)} < \theta + 1.$$

Now subtract one from both sides.